# jQuery get li from nested delete image

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am very close to solving this problem but I can't seem to grab the outer html from my `<li>`.

I am adding my `<li>`'s to a `<ul>` like this

```
    function addTab() {
        tabs.append('<li class="navHighlight">' 
                         + '<a href="#">' 
                         + title 
                         + '</a>' 
                         + '<a href="#">' 
                         + '<img src="images/delete.png" class="deleteImage"/>' 
                         + '</a>' 
                         + '</li>');
    };
```

Then I'm trying to delete them with this

```
$("body").on("click", ".deleteImage", function (e) {
    var removeItem = $(this).closest('li').html(); // problem
    console.log(removeItem);
    listItems = jQuery.grep(listItems, function (value) {
        console.log(value);
        return value != removeItem;
    });
});
```

But the problem is, my remove item variable has this value

```
<a href="#">Test</a><a href="#"><img src="images/delete.png" class="deleteImage" style="display: inline;"></a>
```

and I need it to have the outer html value as well, like this

```
<li><a href="#">Test</a><a href="#"><img src="images/delete.png" class="deleteImage"/></a></li>
```

the class value I initially assign to the `<li>` called "navHighlight" will of been removed by this time because it's only there for aesthetic purposes. It is toggled when another `<li>` item is clicked, so that point of reference is out the window. I've tried a lot of different things, but I can't seem to grab the outer html `<li>` tag.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `outerHTML` to get the outside wrapper `li` as well:

```
var removeItem = $(this).closest('li')[0].outerHTML;
```

Comment: see I was missing the `[0]`. I tried `.outerHTML` and it didn't work. Thank you. now... for some reason it's not removing the item with my grep statement, but that is another problem I will deal with personally. Thanks! answer accepted asap